# Cycling and abs exercises

Tags: abdominals, bicycling

I commute to my work by bicycle everyday except weekend 12.6 km and back (totalling 25.2). I cycle this route in low-intensity between 60%-70% MHR. I would like to add some abs exercises as my belly is a bit bigger than it should be. A friend of mine recommended me some excercises (crunches, leg raises, planking etc.). but I am a bit worried that this might be too much for a body to handle and I might hurt myself or stop losing weight/start gaining weight. I am not even sure if my standard commuting length is not too long and thus counter-productive.

Is it allright to combine cycling (considering the length) and abs exercises in one day?

Comment: Spot reduction is a myth. Simply by doing ab exercises won't burn your belly fat. Get your diet in order. If you cycle that much you should be able to lose weight. Going to the gym would also help of course

Comment: Do you sit at a desk all day? If you do, and you cycle in every day, check out some info on anterior pelvic tilt, see if that's an issue for you (basically, sitting can lead to tight hip flexors and inhibited glutes, lots of cycling can lead to muscle imbalances between the quads and hammies, put them together and you've got a recipe for a bit of a pelvic alignment issue, not to mention some knee issues).

Comment: @DarkHippo Thank you for the warning. Fortunately this is not a problem for me.

Comment: Your body is adapted to your regular commute. Just as someone like the Rock can now regularly do a workout that would destroy a normal person, you are now able to handle the additional ab exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ab specifics exercises I would suggest full body exercises that will work more muscle groups. I am a high mileage cyclist and often lift on the same day.

I suggest this plan:
http://stronglifts.com/5x5/

StrongLifts 5×5 consists of two full body-workouts:

Workout A: Squat, Bench Press, Barbell Row

Workout B: Squat, Overhead Press, Deadlift,

Your abs will definitely be worked. If you want to do even more ab specific work try adding hanging leg lifts and and pull ups

Comment: Thank you, this looks wonderful. I have another question regarding this plan. Would it make too much harm if I keep cycling on the rest day too? I am trying to combine these two things as cycling is right now both exercise and a way to commute effectively. If it would be too much I can find another way to travel on the rest days but I would rather not.

Comment: I would say experiment. In the beginning you will be quite sore, especially after deadlift day. Over time your recover times and soreness will improve. Although I like the program I linked there is nothing wrong with modifying it to fit your needs. For example I often only lift 2 days a week instead of 3 (as in the plan) and avoid my long runs and sessions on days where I deadlift.  If you are going to lift and cycle on the same day the 2nd activity will be harder than normal.

Comment: Another note on the 5x5 plan. Have not pride. I made the mistake in the beginning in adding weight to the bar because I felt silly lifting an empty bar. Follow the plan to learn proper form from the start. By attempting to take shortcuts (adding too much weight, not asking for feedback, from experienced lifters in gym, etc) I picked up a few bad habits (related to squat depth, deadlift form, etc) I had to unlearn

Answer (score -1):

Abs is the worst or one of the worst thing to do if you want to lose belly fat. It is a misconception that fat get lost locally. Do abs if you what to streng that part of your body. Keep doing cycling or running to lose your fat.

Cycling it is really good for losing weight. I went from 84 kg to 68 in less than a year by only cycling. I use and still use the bike for most of my displacements.